# How to send the url of current page to the servlet without refreshing the page

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I want to send the url of current page to the servlet without refreshing or reloading the page. here is the code-

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Action Onclick </title>

    <!--        <script>
                $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
                    alert('sdafjb');
                    return false;
                });            
            </script>-->
</head>
<body>

    <form id="contactForm" >
        <fieldset>
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input id="contactName" type="text" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input id="contactEmail" type="text" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="noHeight">
            <textarea id="contactMessage" cols="20"></textarea>


            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contactForm').submit();"> submit </a>
        </fieldset>

    </form>        
    <small id="messageSent">Your message has been sent.</small>

</body>
```

My servlet's name is scriptservlet. Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

AJAX was built for communicating with a server without reloading or changing the current page in the browser.   You should be able to just create an AJAX call to your server and send your server whatever data you want without affecting the current page.

Under normal circumstances, AJAX calls are restricted to "same origin" which means you can only communicate with a server on the same domain as the current web page so you would also have to make sure that you satisfy this security restriction.

Comment: I think even Javascript must be enabled in the browser for AJAX to work.

Comment: @Sudhanshu - uh yes.  You will need javascript for anything other than a form post or the loading of a new page.

Answer (score 1):

Do an ajax call to the servlet and pass the Url of current page by doing (request.getRequestUri()) to the servlet.

```
var requestUri = '<% request.getRequestUri()%>';
var hostname = location.host;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/scriptServlet",
  data: { "host": hostname, "uri": requestUri  }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
```

Please note, syntax might not be correct but u have to make a ajax callt o achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by sending back the appropriate response code (204 I guess) back to the client from the server (servlet). This way even though the request is submitted the page is not refreshed / reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden field in your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="currentPage" value="<%=request.getRequestURL()%>">
```